# Elementor with Advance custom fields

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

I'm using advance custom fields to create posts for a particular category. I have used Elementor(Free version) to do the formatting, I want that all the posts that are created using ACF should be displayed on my page under a specific section. However, I could not do it because elementor pro supports this functionality and i cannot write php in elementor.

Any idea on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i have read your question you are trying to create the custom posts using the advance custom field , Yes you can do it without  the **Elemento Pro**, you also need the **Extension** with the name  (Elementor Pro Anywhere ). it will help you to build the any type of custom post with the design options..

The idea is you need to purchase it , and the second if you don't have enough money to purchase then let me know i will provide you i have purchased for unlimited websites. Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

After clicking on the add field button, the field form will open up and you need to add custom field information. Add all the parameters in the form and then click on the add field button again.

[image]

To add more custom fields click on the add field button. After adding the custom field information move on to the location section where you can select where to display the field.

Go to the setting section to set style, position, placements, and others set for your custom field.

[image]

When everything is done click on the publish button to activate your newly created custom field.

After publishing your custom field you can again edit the field option from Custom Fields > Field Groups. Here you will see all of your created custom field lists. Just click on the edit option on the custom field you want to edit the information on.

**Add custom field to Elementor**

Your custom field type is created now you need to add the custom field in your Elementor design. You need to have the Elementor pro to add the custom field.

Open up a page with Elementor editor and create a section and add a new widget. Now under the content tab click on the dynamic icon and select Advanced Custom Fields.

[image]

Now it will show you all of your created custom fields list from there you can select the field you want to add.

See this [tutorial](https://themeoo.com/how-to-add-custom-fields-in-elementor/) for a better understanding

Answer (score -1):

I think you can create a shortcode and then paste it into the elementor.